# What was the exact date when the "Bailando" song by "Paradisio" was first released/played?

Tags: release, database

This is a recurring frustration for me: whenever I try to look up the exact date when a song/CD/album was released (whether in stores or started being played on public radio stations), they only ever tell me the *year*! Back in the 1990s, every damn month was like its own "era" to me, so knowing that it was released in "1996" is pretty much useless to me. But that's all the Wikipedia article (and all other sources I can find) says.

Can you tell me the exact date, per-country/region? How do I generally look this up? Why do they only state the year for this? For video games and movies, for example, they almost always have an exact date for each region/country. Why not for CDs/radio releases?

Comment: Your post currently contains many questions in one. I've answered the title question, but the remaining questions should likely be separated out.

Answer (score 2):

It was released on the 19<sup>th</sup> of either May or August, in 1996.

---

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradisio_(album)) for their self titled album Paradisio shows conflicting information. The section titled "*Singles*" claims it was in August:

> "Bailando" was released on 19 August 1996 as the lead single.

However, as of the date of this answer, the information panel on the right side of the article lists a release in the month of May:

[image: Screenshot of the relevant section of the information panel.]

Two things seem certain:

- It was released in 1996.
- It was released on the 19<sup>th</sup> day of the month.